# Setting The Rowfilter On Load

Tags: devexpress

How can I set the Row filter to a value so when the form loads it filters by that columns value in devexpress gridview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought you were using the ASPxGridView.  If you are using a Winforms grid, the code should be:

```
gridView1.ActiveFilterCriteria = new DevExpress.Data.Filtering.BinaryOperator("Status", "P");
```

Comment: That Works....but is there anyway to populate the cell of the rowfilter with the value of "P"?

Comment: gridView1.SetRowCellValue(DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.AutoFilterRowHandle, "Status", "P");

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which should work for you:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ASPxGridView1.FilterExpression = "[CategoryName] = 'Beverages'";
}
```

Comment: I am using winfroms and I dont see a filterExpression property on it all I see is a rowFilter property and its read only

Comment: I set the ShowAutoFilter row to true and it shows a RowFilter row in the grdview which is what I want now on load I wanna set a cell in the column initially to a value....The column is called "Status" and the value I wanna set is "P" which will filter the the grid where status ="P". This works when I manually do it, but I want it to happen on load.